# FFMPEG crop ratio?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I've been trying to figure out how FFMPEG decides it's dimensions after cropping a video. After cropping width 400 by 3 (133.3), it becomes 132. 640 by 3 (213.3) becomes 212. 426 by 2 (213) becomes 212.
I thought it might be int((dimension+1)/crop) - 1 (such as (400-1/3) -1 becomes 132 which is correct) but this fails on 720/2 which becomes 359, but it should be 360. Any ideas?

Comment: You should show the full command and console output for the 426 and 720 examples.

Comment: it was in the format `ffmpeg -i vid.mp4 -vf scale=iw/3:ih/3 out.mp4` for all of them

Comment: That command is scaling the video, not cropping it. Show the console output for the 720 execution.

Comment: sorry, replace scale with crop. The 406x720 video when cropped by iw/2:ih/2 becomes 202x360, but using my algo it should be 202x359. My algo is wrong and I want to know what the correct algo is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Crop rounds down width/height values so that they can fit whole number of chroma components. So for common case of `yuv420p` pixel format that means rounding down to even numbers.

UPDATE: FFmpeg v3.2 and newer will support `exact=1` option for `crop` filter which disables this behaviour.

Comment: With a recent build of ffmpeg,  adding `exact=1` will avoid this.

Comment: @user3730954 For me, usually by reading the [documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#crop), subscribing to the FFmpeg mailing lists, submitting the occasional patch, answering questions from other users, looking at the source code, using `ffmpeg` at work, and not having a social life.

Comment: @Mulvya thank you for the comment, I've updated the answer accordingy.